# In SSRS report manager can not see New folder, new dat source, upload file etc. options?

Tags: reporting-services, rdl, reportmanager

I am trying to use report manager to deploy report. I am newbie on SSRS.

When i opened report manager URL i see something like this.

[image: My report Manager]
[image]

So I could not find any way to upload rdl/create dataset etc. When I googled I got following image.

[image: Googled Report Manager]

[image]

Here there are options to deploy report..what could be the reason I am not bale to see this?

Comment: Security perhaps? Have you given your user the appropriate rights? See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156034.aspx) for a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

First, if you are executing the report locally, you should **Run** the IE **as Administrator** and if the folders still are no shown you should configure the **Site Settings** and add the curent user.